# What does "&:name" mean in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I saw it in some sample Ruby code someone had posted. It was something like:

```
a.sort_by(&:name)
```

where `a` is an array or ActiveRecord objects and `:name` is one of the attributes.

I have never seen `&:name` and Ruby's Symbol class documentation says nothing about it. Probably something really simple. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unary [Ampersand](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby/) is address of a function/block/lambda

In this case, it means that the `.sort_by` function will use each `a`'s element's function named `name` for comparison

Mostly it used for something else, like this:

```
[1,2,3].map{ |x| x.to_s } # ['1','2','3']
```

That could be shortened as:

```
[1,2,3].map(&:to_s)
```

So, in your case, `a.sort_by(&:name)` is a shorthand to:

```
a.sort_by{ |x| x.name }
```